# xsd type usage in extension

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

When you look at the xml file, I think my xsd body is true. But xml file is checked by python xml library and program print "file is not valid".When I delete nameType and write xsd:string instead of `<xsd:extension base="nameType">` it prints "file is valid".So where should change at xsd file

```
 <xsd:element name="name">
<xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:extension base="nameType">
        <xsd:attribute name="ÖĞRENİM_TÜRÜ" type="nameType"/>
        <xsd:attribute type="nameType" name="DİL" />
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This is the xsd part. nameType is special type . It's like that:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="nameType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="io"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="oo"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Eng"/>
      <xsd:enumeration value="Tr"/>
    </xsd:restriction> 
 </xsd:simpleType>
```

Xml is :

```
 <university UNIVERSITE="IZMIR KATIP ÇELEBI UNIVERSITESI" UNIVERSITE_TURU="Devlet">
<item PROGRAM_KODU="105710042" FAKÜLTE="Muhendislik ve Mimarlik Fakultesi">
  <name OGRENIM_TÜRÜ="oo" DIL="Eng">Elektrik-Elektronik Mühendisligi</name>
  <period>4</period>
  <grant>0</grant>
  <quota OKUL_BIRINCISI_KONTENJANI="2">70</quota>
  <field>SAY</field>
  <last_min_score>395,14565
</last_min_score>
</item>
</university>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a complex type with simple content, the base type in xs:extension defines constraints on the element content, that is the text node which here is `Elektrik-Elektronik Mühendisligi`. This does not satisfy any of the values permitted by the enumeration. I think you want `<xsd:extension base="xs:string">`

Comment: Actually I am trying to write a xsd which "OGRENIM_TÜRÜ" can be only io or oo ,and "DİL" can be only Eng or Tr

Comment: Fine, then (a) use different enumeration types for the two attributes, and (b) don't use an enumeration type for the element content.